# Getting 404 when trying to run HelloWorld REST service

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm following the example on https://medium.com/@jamsesso/starting-out-with-jersey-apache-tomcat-using-intellij-6338d93ffd40#.9rmard5sl

I've read the question on not resolving com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory and got past that (thanks!)

Here's my code:

```
package com.webbo.acronymserver;
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by mark on 8/3/17.
 */
// The Java class will be hosted at the URI path "/helloworld"
@Path("/helloworld")
public class acronymServer {
    // The Java method will process HTTP GET requests
    @GET
    // The Java method will produce content identified by the MIME Media type "text/plain"
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getClichedMessage() {
        // Return some cliched textual content
        return "Hello World";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:8080/");
        server.start();

    }
}
```

Here's the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.jersey</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I'm running in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.3. Zipped project directory available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2gjwgzj7wbkb5k/acronymServer.zip?dl=0

All I get is a 404? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you'll get help much faster.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had. What's missing?

Comment: A complete zipped project directory.

Comment: Available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2gjwgzj7wbkb5k/acronymServer.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project that you have shared has a lot of configuration issues, to name a few:

- sources location doesn't correspond to the standard Maven layout (`/src/main/java`), therefore Java classes are not compiled at all
- web app location also is not correct (should be `/src/main/webapp`)
- dependencies configured manually (`lib` directory) and via Maven
- dependencies not added to the artifact that is deployed on the server
- Maven packaging is not set to `war`
- duplicate and incorrectly configured web facets
- startup URL is set to the root of the context instead of `http://localhost:8080/helloworld` servlet `@Path`

I've fixed the main problems so that it starts and displays `Hello World`, the rest will be your home task.

[image: structure]

You can download the fixed project [here](https://mega.nz/#!QpRGGBAT!mA7vNz3X94g6uwwfiAkG1jDDXfo-_fJVdxASZfwpmj4). Don't forget to change the **Application server** in the run/debug configuration since I tested with a different Tomcat version.

Comment: Wow! That's awesome help. Thank you very much. I simply reconfigured to run the version of tomcat I have, and it worked straight away. A lot of the configuration you fixed for me was automatically generated by IDEA, so I'm not sure how it went so pear shaped? Anyway, thanks again. I now have a working template I can build on.

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing your api? It should be `http://localhost:8080/<webapp context>/helloworld`

Comment: I've been using the 'run tomcat' command in intelliJ IDEA, which goes to http://localhost:8080, I also add the /helloworld URI on the address bar of the browser, i.e. http://localhost:8080/helloworld, but that gives the same result i.e. 404. What is my web app context? I've tried the name of my class 'acronymserver', the name of my package 'com.webbo.acronymserver', but neither work. Where is this defined?

Comment: It is basically the web app name by default.