# Running a Jersey application using GlassFish in IntelliJ gives requested resource is not available error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, jersey, glassfish

I have created a small Jersey application which has the following resource class.

```
@Path("/tests")
public class TestController {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response testJob(@PathParam("testName") String testName) {
        return Response.ok("test").build();
    }
}
```

Below is my application class.

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    // All request scoped resources and providers
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(TestController.class);
        return classes;
    }

    // all singleton resources and providers
    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

Below is my running configuration in intellij.

[image]

I just downloaded the glass fish and did no external configurations. I searched online for the default user name password for domain and gave it them as admin and admin respectively. But when I run the application using the URL,

```
http://localhost:8080/test-processor/tests
```

I am getting a 404 error saying the requested resource is not found. My war module name is test-processor. I have tried the url http://localhost:8080/tests with no luck as well. What am  I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated. Below is the list of dependencies I have added in my pom xml.

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guice</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: add web.xml and other configs

Comment: In glassfish 4 web xml is not needed right? That is covered by extending the application class?

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42688676/104891) helps.

Comment: Just a guess here, but make sure that your context root is really what you think it is. E.g. Maven may be adding something like `-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` to the end of your project name. Try going to the GlassFish admin console on `http://localhost:4848`, clicking "Applications" in the tree on the side and looking at your deployment there. There should be a link to launch your application there too, providing it has deployed properly.