# Why i am getting 404 found error in JSP&servlets in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.2?

Tags: jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am creating simple Login web app in jsp and servlet in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.2.

The following is my index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/LoginServlet">
    UerName:<input type="text" name="t1"><br>
    Password:<input type="text" name="t2"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Ok"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my servlet. It is located at src->main->java->francis

```
@WebServlet(name = "LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Welcome.....");
    }
}
```

Web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>francis.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

But the Output screen is...

[image: My Output Screen]

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you get if you go directly to localhost?

Comment: The first page index.jsp runs and when i click add button the above output comes

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/42688676/104891 help?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. But the given config is correct in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<form method="post" action="/LoginServlet">
```

with

```
<form method="post" action="LoginServlet">
```

which will be automatically be translated into `the-context-path/LoginServlet`. Note that the path you put into `action` attribute is relative to the context path.